# ActiveMQ: copy messages from broker to broker

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

We have a requirement to copy messages from one ActiveMQ broker to another. Here the message has to just copy and the message should exist in both broker.

I can think of a custom application that subscribes to a certain destination and read that message and re-post the messages to the destination in multiple brokers.

I do not have access to make changes in the Broker so I couldn't think of [Network of Brokers](https://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html) option.

Is there any best practice or tools available to copy A-MQ messages from one broker to another?

Answer (score 0):

Without having access to the target broker, as far as I know and I have read, I believe there is not shortcut to avoid the custom application that re-post those messages.

However, depending on the messages you want to re-post, there might be some functionalities offered by ActiveMQ that could facilitate your implementation (but they would not be for free, regarding the computational costs).

For example, in the case you want to copy ***ALL*** the messages sent through that broker to the other, then you might consider using [Mirrored Queues](https://activemq.apache.org/mirrored-queues), with a specific prefix (e.g. "copy"), that would allow you to just have a single consumer using a [wildcard](https://activemq.apache.org/wildcards) after that prefix (e.g. "copy.>"). That consumer would get ***ALL*** the messages sent to the broker, and it would simplify your implementation since you would just have to care about that single consumer and re-post from it. However this has costs, since as it is described in the documentation, enabling the mirrored queues will make a duplicate of each queue/topic in the system, and will post each message twice. You need to consider if this is an important inconvenient in your case, depending on the amount of messages and the available memory that your broker disposes.

In case you just wanted to copy ***SOME*** of the messages and not all, then I believe the most elegant way to handle it is by creating an abstraction of your Consumer class (or specific implementation), and use that special implementation for those queues you want to re-post. That class would be responsible of re-posting the messages to the other broker, in a way that would be transparent from the other Consumer class when using it.

I have talked above about consumers, but the same concept could apply to topics and subscribers. Hope these ideas help :)